# PowerShell - Add new line when appending multiple files

Tags: powershell, append

I am trying to create a single file by appending multiple files in a folder. In between the files i wanted to add a new line character . I have tried out the below but it does not work. Please suggest what am i missing.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sql |sort CreationTime| % { Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0 | Add-Content combined_files.sql| Add-Content combined_files.sql -value `n"dummy text before next file" }
```

I am able to get the combined_files.sql created with the contents of child files but the text inbetween files is missing. Please suggest.

Comment: Both [backtick r] and [backtick n] should be placed within the string quotes.

Comment: i tried that out as well. Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing your data before writing it out

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sql | Sort-Object CreationTime | ForEach-Object { 
    $ThisFile = (Get-Content $_.FullName) + "`ndummy text before next file"
    Add-Content -Path combined_files.sql -Value $Thisfile
}
```